# Azure DevOps - Maximum backlog levels allowed is 5

Tags: azure-devops

I have a number of teams in the Azure DevOps (Visual Studio Online) tracking a different type of work item.

Currently i have created 3 different backlogs for 3 different teams.
There is 2 default backlogs 'Epics' and 'Features', hence total of 5 backlogs.

I'm trying to added a 4th team and now trying to add a backlog for that team.
But i'm getting the message **"You have reached the maximum number of backlog levels"**.

I also learnt that maximum number of allowed Portfolio backlog levels defined for a process is 5.

I also tried to edit the default backlog, which would not let me de-select the work item selected in it, so i could rename it and add the new work item it needs to track.

So is there any other way i could achieve that or to increase the number of portfolio backlog levels.

Comment: Did any of these answers lead to solving your problem? Consider accepting one that does!

Answer (score 1):

By default projects, your hierarchy is shown as below:

[image]

If you need more than two portfolio backlogs, you can add up to two more for a total of five backlog levels.  (limits  mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/object-limits?view=azure-devops). Portfolio backlog levels defined for a process 5)

This will increase the totally level to 7 (3 customized+ Epic+Feature+PBI+Task)

You can add them by customizing your process, adding new work item types, and then configuring your backlogs and boards.

You can also add or modify the fields defined for a work item type (WIT) or add a custom WIT.

After this it could be:

[image]

For details, see [Customize an inheritance process and Customize your backlogs or boards (Inheritance process)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/customize-process-backlogs-boards?view=azure-devops).

---

However, this is backlog level not designed for multiple teams.

**Your team's product backlog lists only those items whose area path matches those assigned to your team.**

For details, see [Define area paths and assign to a team](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/set-area-paths?toc=/azure/devops/organizations/settings/scale/toc.json&bc=/azure/devops/organizations/settings/scale/breadcrumb/toc.json&view=azure-devops).

Then you could simply switch backlog for different teams here:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be going about this the wrong way with respect to Azure DevOps.

You should look into having an *Area Path* for each Team. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/set-area-paths?view=azure-devops). For instance in my company we have two Teams say; Alpha and Omega and we've set up two Area Paths as `Company\Alpha` and `Company\Omega`. You can then manage each teams backlogs, iterations, work items etc. separately. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/about-teams-and-settings?view=azure-devops) also. We use the same set of iterations across all teams and when we move work items between teams we change the Area Path of the work items.